# Angular doesn't retrieve updated_at in laravel

Tags: angularjs, laravel

i'm trying to retrieve the updated_at time but it gets the created_at time instead even when i passed it in the angular scope function

and renders the incorrect date on created_at after the update has been made

My console reads when updated

> 1 second ago

so it works but its not getting passed in the view correctly.

**PostController**

```
public function update(Post $post)
{
    //
    $data = request()->validate([
        'body' => 'required|string'
    ]);
    $this->authorize('update', $post);
    $post->update($data);
    $data['id'] = $post->id;
    $data['updatedAt'] = $post->updated_at->diffForHumans();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($data));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

    return $response;

}

public function getPosts()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user')
                 ->with(['likes' => function ($query) {
                            $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                            $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                        }])
                    ->get();
    $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 


    $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post)
    { 
        $user = auth()->user();

        if($user->can('delete', $post)) {
            $post['deletable'] = true;
        }

        if($user->can('update', $post)) {
            $post['update'] = true;
        }

        $post['likedByMe'] = $post->likes->count() == 0 ? false : true;
        $post['likesCount'] = Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->get()->count();
        $post['createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();
        $data['updatedAt'] = $post->updated_at->diffForHumans();
        return $post;
    });

    return response()->json($data); 
}
```

**main.js**

```
$scope.updatePost = function(post){

    $http.post('/auth/upost/' + post.id, {
        body: post.body,
        updatedAt:post.updatedAt

    }).then(function(result, status, headers, config){

         $scope.updatedAt = result.data.updatedAt;
         console.log($scope.updatedAt);
         $scope.myposts.push($scope.updatedAt); 
    });
};
```

**html**

```
<div id="mypost" class="col-md-8 panel-default animated zoomIn" ng-repeat="post in myposts ">
    <div id="eli-style-heading" class="panel-heading"><% post.user.name %></div>
    <div class="panel-body panel" ng-init="getLikeText(post); getLikecount(post)">  


    <i style="color:tomato; float:right; font-size:24px;" ng-click="like(post); toggle = !toggle" 
    ng-class="{[noheart] : !post.likedByMe, [heart]: post.likedByMe }">
        <h3 style="font-size:20px; margin:20px 0px; text-align:center;"  ng-bind="post.likesCount">   </h3>
    </i>


        <figure>
            <p class="mybody" ng-model="post.body" editable-text="post.body" e-form="textBtnForm"> <% post.body %></p>
            <p name="post.created_at" > <% post.createdAt %> <% post.updatedAt %> </p>
        </figure>
        <span>

         <i style="color:red;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="deletePost(post)" ng-if="post.deletable"></i>


              <button ng-if="post.update" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="textBtnForm.$show()" ng-hide="textBtnForm.$visible">
                Edit
              </button>

            <span><button ng-if="post.update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="updatePost(post)">Update</button></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct code my bad for this silly question guys.

```
 public function getPosts()
    {
        $posts = Post::with('user')
                     ->with(['likes' => function ($query) {
                                $query->whereNull('deleted_at');
                                $query->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                            }])
                        ->get();
        $response = new Response(json_encode($posts));
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 


        $data = $posts->map(function(Post $post)
        { 
            $user = auth()->user();

            if($user->can('delete', $post)) {
                $post['deletable'] = true;
            }

            if($user->can('update', $post)) {
                $post['update'] = true;
            }

            $post['likedByMe'] = $post->likes->count() == 0 ? false : true;
            $post['likesCount'] = Like::where('post_id', $post->id)->get()->count();
            $post['createdAt'] = $post->created_at->diffForHumans();

            // $data['updatedAt'] = $post->updated_at->diffForHumans();
            //calling again if the post has been updated
            $post['createdAt'] = $post->updated_at->diffForHumans();
            return $post;
        });

        return response()->json($data); 
    }
```

main.js

remove this its useless and renders out a box

```
 $scope.myposts.push($scope.updatedAt);
```

html

`<% post.createdAt %>` is all you need it will render both the created time and updated time